# Why does Apple clang++ not support std::ifstream?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I have a very simple, quite standard piece of C++, which I can compile fine using `g++`<sup>1</sup>, but which Apple `clang++`<sup>2</sup> is unable to compile:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("test.cpp");
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ clang++ -o test test.cpp

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, unsigned int) in test-2f8096.o
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, unsigned int) in test-2f8096.o
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_filebuf()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, unsigned int) in test-2f8096.o
      std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ifstream() in test-2f8096.o
  "VTT for std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, unsigned int) in test-2f8096.o
      std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ifstream() in test-2f8096.o
  "vtable for std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, unsigned int) in test-2f8096.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can't see why Apple `clang++` would have difficulty with this piece of code as it uses nothing outside the standard library.

<sup>1: g++ version: Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_3</sup>
<sup>2: clang++ version: Apple clang version 13.1.6</sup>

---

EDIT: This has been resolved by factory resetting the computer this was on (for other reasons). It was probably a configuration error.

Comment: You are getting *linker* errors, not *compiler* errors. Make sure your project is configured correctly to find your compiler's installed libraries.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling the file? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Try `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -o test test.cpp`.

Comment: @273K Now it complains about file `<wchar.h>` not being found.

Comment: Look for this error, it has been answered a bunch of times - not proper xcode development tools installation.

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` to remove the command line tools (since they appear broken), and then `sudo xcode-select --install` to re-install the command line tools.

Comment: @Eljay Didn't really help, I still get the error about `<wchar.h>` missing, I just don't get the error about the `missing vtable` anymore.

Comment: Drat, sorry it didn't work.  It did work for me with similar problem, and I had gotten the advice from `brew doctor`.