# How can I resolve Undefined Symbols when using std::ofstream on a Mac

Tags: c++, macos, clang, ld, undefined-symbol

**UPDATE:** I am including the isolated call to `ld` as well.  And providing a second sample `main` function that *does* succcessfully compile, link, and call into `std::` methods.  Both appear at the end of this edited post.  Also, I have tried providing `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` compiler options, along with many other attempts to get `clang` to find/link the correct library.  These produce the same undefined symbol errors.

I can't understand why the linker is able to find `std::out` (in the working example) but not `std::ofstream` (in the example that fails).

### Original problem description:

Compiling on my Mac, I am getting Undefined Symbols when using `std::ofstream`.

I have re-installed the XCode command line tools and tried every permutation of library paths and switches I could find.  I've tried "clang++" and "g++" to compile this code, but continue to get linker Undefined Symbol errors on my Mac (OSX 12.6.3, XCode 14.2 (14C18)).

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Here is my short C++ file, `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argv, char*[]) 
{
    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    out << "This is output written to a file\n";
}
```

And here is me trying to compile it:

```
% g++ foo.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-d774c2.o
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-d774c2.o
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_filebuf()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-d774c2.o
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ofstream() in foo-d774c2.o
  "VTT for std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-d774c2.o
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ofstream() in foo-d774c2.o
  "vtable for std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-d774c2.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And here is me trying to compile it with `-v` to reveal compiler and linker options, search paths, etc:

```
% g++ -v foo.cpp
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx12.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name foo.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -target-sdk-version=13.1 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 820.1 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-bitwise-instead-of-logical -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/ghassett/tmp -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+messageToSelfInClassMethodIdReturnType -clang-vendor-feature=+disableInferNewAvailabilityFromInit -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /var/folders/gp/4g1pmgt925gbj7mrwgsjlxbc0000gn/T/foo-55ecc8.o -x c++ foo.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202) default target x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 12.0.0 13.1 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o a.out -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/gp/4g1pmgt925gbj7mrwgsjlxbc0000gn/T/foo-55ecc8.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-55ecc8.o
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-55ecc8.o
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_filebuf()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-55ecc8.o
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ofstream() in foo-55ecc8.o
  "VTT for std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-55ecc8.o
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ofstream() in foo-55ecc8.o
  "vtable for std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo-55ecc8.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

### Isolated linker command:

The isolated call to `ld` looks like this -- note that `-lc++` is provided to the linker:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld \
-demangle \
-lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib \
-no_deduplicate \
-dynamic \
-arch x86_64 \
-platform_version macos 12.0.0 13.1 \
-syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk \
-o a.out \
-L/usr/local/lib \
foo.o \
-lc++ \
-lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

The output is the same:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo.o
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo.o
  "std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_filebuf()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo.o
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ofstream() in foo.o
  "VTT for std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo.o
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ofstream() in foo.o
  "vtable for std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(char const*, unsigned int) in foo.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

### Example that successfully links and uses std:

This code compiles, links, and executes:

```
% cat works.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argv, char*[]) 
{
    std::cout << "Writing to the console works\n";
}                                                                                                                                                                   

% g++ works.cpp -o works

% ./works
Writing to the console works
```

Thanks so much for any help you might be able to provide!

Comment: Your compiler is broken, try reinstalling it, or install stock clang or stock gcc (versions shipped by Apple sometimes behave strangely).

Comment: I reinstalled the command line tools via `xcode-select --reset` followed by `xcode-select --install` and watched as my Mac downloaded the tools and re-installed them (took 10 minutes).  I restarted my command line (Terminal) window with a very stripped down PATH to remove the possibility that other software might be interfering with the invocation of `g++`. Same result. Crazy.

Comment: Looks like same story as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888715/why-does-apple-clang-not-support-stdifstream), no one really knows why it is broken, just ignore tools shipped by Apple and install stock ones with homebrew or something.

Comment: Thanks for your help -- the answer is yes, I have also tried building this code in XCode and it does compile, link, and run.  Like you, I also wish people would explain the downvote -- normally it indicates that they feel I did not try hard enough to solve the problem on my own, or that I didn't include enough information for other users. Believe me, I have tried everything I can think of and I am not a novice at this sort of thing, having built many toolchains for cross compiling, multiple architecture support, etc.  This one has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: There had to have been a conflict between some developer tools installed via homebrew and the XCode command line tools. Some combination of `brew update`, `brew upgrade`, `brew doctor`, and `brew unlink llvm` has done the trick and my little application now compiles and links.  Thanks to everyone who helped out.  I realize that my answer here is imperfect but hopefully it will still be of help to someone down the line.